# How to handle memory management for custom modal dialog setup/teardown

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Currently my app is using a custom modal dialog object when I'm waiting for a web service

```
@implementation AddModalDialog

- (void)buildModalDialogWithTextForView:(NSString *)text:(UIViewController *)controller
{
  UIView* _hudView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 450)];
  _hudView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
  _hudView.clipsToBounds = YES;

  UIActivityIndicatorView* _activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
  _activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 135, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.width, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.height);
  [_hudView addSubview:_activityIndicatorView];
  [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

  UILabel* _captionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 190, 250, 22)];
  _captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  _captionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  _captionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
  _captionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
  _captionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  _captionLabel.text = text;
  [_hudView addSubview:_captionLabel];

  [controller.view addSubview:_hudView];
}

- (void)removeModalDialogForView:(UIViewController *)controller
{
  NSUInteger i, count = [controller.view.subviews count];
  [[controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:(count - 1)] removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

My question is related to memory management when using this object.  And anything you might notice inside the custom UIView above is welcome as it has room for improvement I'm sure.

Here is how I currently work w/ this in my other objects when I want to pull up the modal

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  AddModalDialog* modal = [[AddModalDialog alloc] init];
  [modal buildModalDialogWithTextForView:@"Loading some details ..." :self];
  [modal release];
}
```

Then after a web service is complete I typically call the tear down

```
- (void)returnWebServiceDetails:(MyClass *)obj
{ 
  AddModalDialog* modal = [[AddModalDialog alloc] init];
  [modal removeModalDialogForView:self];
  [modal release];
}
```

Should I not init this object twice and instead have a property?  New obj-c developer looking for a best practice around this behavior.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you effectively transfer ownership of these items to the controller's view (since you keep no references to them around), so you should release them all after adding them to the controller's subview.

Second, instead of assuming you know the structure of the controller's view heirarchy, you should instead tag your _hudView with something that hopefully doesn't conflict with anything else in your application, and use that to retrieve your view.

Third, since you keep no references around at all, these would be better off as class methods instead of instances. There is no need to create an instance of this object just to have it add some views and go away.

So your same code, following these three guidelines, might look like this:

```
@interface AddModalDialog {
}

+ (void)buildModalDialogWithText:(NSString *)text forController:(UIViewController *)controller;
+ (void)removeModalDialogForController:(UIViewController *)controller;

@end

@implementation AddModalDialog

// Class methods: use '+' instead of '-'
+ (void)buildModalDialogWithText:(NSString *)text forController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
  UIView* _hudView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 450)];
  _hudView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
  _hudView.clipsToBounds = YES;
  _hudView.tag = 2000; // use something that won't clash with tags you may already use

  UIActivityIndicatorView* _activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
  _activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 135, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.width, _activityIndicatorView.bounds.size.height);
  [_hudView addSubview:_activityIndicatorView];
  [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
  [_activityIndicatorView release]; // _hudView owns this now

  UILabel* _captionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 190, 250, 22)];
  _captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  _captionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  _captionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
  _captionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
  _captionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  _captionLabel.text = text;
  [_hudView addSubview:_captionLabel];
  [_captionLabel release]; // _hudView owns this now

  [controller.view addSubview:_hudView];
  [_hudView release]; // the controller's view owns this now
}

// Class methods: use '+' instead of '-'
+ (void)removeModalDialogForController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
  UIView* _hudView = [controller.view viewWithTag:2000];
  [_hudView removeFromSuperView]; // owned by the view, so we don't need to do anything more
}

@end
```

And you would use it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  // Class methods, so we don't need to create an instance to use
  [AddModalDialog buildModalDialogWithText:@"Loading some details..." forController:self];
}

- (void)returnWebServiceDetails:(id)obj
{
  // Class methods, so we don't need to create an instance to use
  [AddModalDialog removeModalDialogForController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `buildModalDialogWithTextForView` at it's bottom, do release on `_activityIndicatorView`, `_captionLabel` and `_hudView` - you are the owner of those (by creating them). Otherwise, they will just leak.

More about [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB) and CoreFoundation [Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH)